# Posting JSON object in HTTP in Java class

Tags: java, json, object

This is the error I am getting when I post a JSON as `json.toString()` 
Am stuck with this problem. Need help to overcome this as early as possible

```
Error code -415
Unsupported Media Type.
```

Code is

```
String url = "http://0.0.0.0:0000/XXXX/XXXX?wsdl";
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("headerValue", "HeaderInformation");

        //setting json object to post request.
        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonValue();
        if(jsonObject!=null ){
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF8");
            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(entity);

            //this is your response:
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println("jsonObject is Empty");
```

Comment: since you have not provide any more details, the message says clear that it is unsupported, so we need to see more or learn more details to be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your service that is accepting the post does not accept te media type you provide. It is probably annotated with @Consumes (something). You need to find what something is it. You have to specify the media type explicitly when posting.

For example JAX-RS client API:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig()
            .register(MyClientResponseFilter.class)
            .register(new AnotherClientFilter()));

String entity = client.target("http://example.com/rest")
            .register(FilterForExampleCom.class)
            .path("resource/helloworld")
            .queryParam("greeting", "Hi World!")
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .header("some-header", "true")
            .get(String.class);
```

In your case you need to change:

`.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)`

Look here: [Jersey Client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)